# Linux: Move log files from a mounted dir to a local dir recursively while maintaining directory structure in local direcoty

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04

So I've done a fair bit of Googling and I haven't found the answer to this yet. I have one server that needs to be live and respond quickly - I don't want my visitors/customers waiting. However, I've had enough server issues to know that I need a good backup and not the whenever I feel like it backups I've got now.

When I've tried mysqldump and tar on this server it works but makes the server is quite slow for hours. It can also lead to filling up the hard drive (if I forget to remove old backups for too long) which takes down MySQL and by extension my sites. Slowing down the server is unacceptable so my backups to date only happen about once a week on the most common slow day/time. However, I'm not fond of this solution.

So I now have another server that I have set up as my primary server's near real-time backup. I am setting up MySQL replication and a daily rsync. Then a daily mysqldump and tar can be run from this backup server without effecting response times on the primary. Great except I'd like to take it a step further.

I have a number of data files that get captured throughout the day - like log files and basic visitor tracking files (IP, referrer, user agent, nothing evil) - that don't need to be processed in real time and I've decided that it is best to have this backup server process these files rather than tie up my primary server's resources. This creates an issue for me though. I want to get these files off the primary server and onto my backup server for processing. The files are scattered across a lot of directories and that list of directories will only grow over time. So I want to avoid having run mv on several directories now and having to maintain that list going forward - some new directory will get forgotten eventually.

So I've mounted the necessary directory on the primary server under the /media folder on the backup server. If I just wanted to copy the files over I'd use scp but I want move them. So I'd like a command that does something like:

```
mv /media/primary/*.log /backup/.
```

where the mv command recursively looks into the /media/primary folder and goes down through the directory to each subfolder looking for any file with the .log extension. Then moves that file from /media/primary/ to an equivalent folder on /backup. So, for example, if I had log files in the directories /media/primary/tool1/logs and /media/primary/tool2/logs I'd like them moved to /backup/tool1/logs and /backup/tool2/logs respectively. I'd like (but don't require) that the command create the folder if it is missing. Once properly moved the files can then be processed and renamed/deleted from the local hard drive on the backup server.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 server for both machines. I work primarily in PHP so I've been creating a PHP script for the backup server to be executed daily. The script can execute system commands via SSH (phpseclib).

A single command for the CLI would be great but I understand that may not be possible.

Thanks

Comment: How about something like `rsync -azrR --include='*.log' -f 'hide,! */' /media/primary /backup`?

Comment: So I see the -azrR gets me archive, compress, recursive, and relative path. I understand the --include portion. However, I'm not sue what the 'hide,!' portion would do. According to the man page it would remove files and directories on the destination. I don't want anything removed from the destination. I want the files moved from the primary to the backup server. Did I misunderstand the file filter?

Comment: If you use `man rsync` and type `2343g` it should take you to the line where it explains this filter. Basically it will hide everything that's not a directory (every file) from the pattern matching; however, since I've used the `--include='*.log'` flag as well it will override that and the pattern will match only `.log` files. You can also use the `-nv` flag to do a dry run and see what would happen.

Comment: OK so I did the dry run... It appears to recursively search the directory tree and find the log files. With the --remove-source-files option it appears that I could also delete the files from the primary drive. The dry run didn't tell me that much other than that it traversed the directory tree and specified the individual log files it found. However, it did not say moving or delete or anything else before or after the line with the full file name and path. However, this shows potential. I'll try it out. @Conner can you make this an answer so I can mark it as such? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
rsync -azrR --include='*.log' -f 'hide,! */' /media/primary /backup
```

If you use `man rsync` and type `2343g` it should take you to the line where it explains this filter. Basically it will hide everything that's not a directory (every file) from the pattern matching; however, since I've used the `--include='*.log'` flag as well it will override that and the pattern will match only `.log` files. You can also use the `-nv` flag to do a dry run and see what would happen.

Comment: This appeared to work in the dry run but I think will require the --remove-source-files option in order to remove the files from /media/primary. I haven't yet tested it (other issues came up) but I'll add a comment here if it doesn't work or needs further tweaking.